# Can I monkey patch a method defined with define_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, monkeypatching

I've tried to fix a situation where updatng records fails because the id of an associated collection is forced to integer while the ids are uuids (to_i on a uuid returns the first numeric part).
The following snippet shows the monkey patch I've tried (coment #.map(&:to_i)). Although the patch is loaded the original method is accessed.

Making the change in the ActiveRecord module works for me but I'd prefer a patch over freezing the rails code.

I'd be grateful for any hint what I'm missing.

```
<!-- language: ruby -->

module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    module ClassMethods
      private
            def collection_accessor_methods(reflection, association_proxy_class, writer = true)
              collection_reader_method(reflection, association_proxy_class)

              if writer
                define_method("#{reflection.name}=") do |new_value|
                  # Loads proxy class instance (defined in collection_reader_method) if not already loaded
                  association = send(reflection.name)
                  association.replace(new_value)
                  association
                end

                define_method("#{reflection.name.to_s.singularize}_ids=") do |new_value|
                  ids = (new_value || []).reject { |nid| nid.blank? } #.map(&:to_i)
                  send("#{reflection.name}=", reflection.klass.find(ids).index_by(&:id).values_at(*ids))
                end
              end
            end
```

The error message is e.g.

"Couldn't find PosperCategory with ID=281"

The root cause is that '218' is what '.map(&:to_i' makes of the original UUID. I need to use UUIDs because the rails app and a Java app use the same legacy database.
This worked in rails 2.2.2, ceased to work in 2.3.2, worked again in 2.3.3 (I think) and stopped working again. I'm now on 2.3.18. Upgrading to rails 3.x is not an option for me out of reasons which should not be discussed here.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting when the record update fails?

Comment: @thohl I've updated my question with the error message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to define dynamic method in mokey patching

## example

```
class Object
  def methods(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method("#{name}=") do |value, &b|
        puts "setter"
        puts __method__
      end

      define_method("#{name}") do
        puts "getter"
        puts __method__
      end
    end
  end
end

module Module
  def n_attrib_keys(*names)
    Object.methods(*names)
  end
end
```

## Include module to your class